# Vscode Terminal automatically changes from PowerShell to Node

Tags: node.js, react-native, powershell, npm, terminal

This must be a stupid question but I'm gonna ask anyway. The Vscode Terminal Automatically changes from PowerShell to Node once I run a npm command.

[image]

This changed when i ran a npm command:
[image]

I am not sure how this automatically changes.

Comment: It looks like `npm start` launches a `node.exe` process synchronously. You could try to run it in the background, with `$job = Start-Job { Set-Location $using:PWD; npm start }` or, in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) more simply: `$job = npm start &`